# Power Query to filter only numbers

Tags: powerquery

I've been searching everywhere to find a way to filter a column that contains both Text and Numbers, I want to filter out the numbers only from that column.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add column, custom column, potentially with one of these

= Text.Select([Column1],{"0".."9"})

=try Number.From([Column1]) otherwise "Text"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let

//Change next line to reflect Data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],

//change next line to include all columns and their names
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"COLUMN", type any}}),

//Change next line to be testing the proper column
    #"Numbers Only" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each not (try Number.From([COLUMN]))[HasError]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Numbers Only",{{"COLUMN", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]